# How to remove a package and all unneeded dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I want to remove `kdenlive` from my Arch Linux. I also want to remove all packages that are needed **only** by `kdenlive`. I tried doing

```
sudo pacman -Rnsu kdenlive
```

Here's what I see when I run the command:

```
checking dependencies...
:: google-chrome optionally requires kwallet: for storing passwords in KWallet
:: imagemagick optionally requires libzip: OpenRaster support
:: libreoffice-fresh optionally requires kio: for KF5 KDE desktop integration
:: qt5-base optionally requires qt5-wayland: to run Qt applications in a Wayland session
:: root optionally requires qt5-webengine: Support for WebGUI
:: vlc optionally requires kwallet: kwallet keystore
:: zoom optionally requires qt5-webengine: SSO login support
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: usbmuxd will be removed after its libimobiledevice dependency

Packages (80) accounts-qml-module-0.7-4  attica-5.94.0-1  breeze-icons-5.94.0-1  cdparanoia-10.2-8
              convertlit-1.8-10  ebook-tools-0.2.2-7  frei0r-plugins-1.7.0-2  gavl-1.4.0-6
              graphene-1.10.8-1  gst-plugins-base-1.20.2-1  kaccounts-integration-22.04.1-1
              karchive-5.94.0-1  kauth-5.94.0-1  kbookmarks-5.94.0-1  kcmutils-5.94.0-1
              kcodecs-5.94.0-1  kcompletion-5.94.0-1  kconfig-5.94.0-1  kconfigwidgets-5.94.0-1
              kcoreaddons-5.94.0-1  kcrash-5.94.0-1  kdbusaddons-5.94.0-1  kdeclarative-5.94.0-1
              kded-5.94.0-1  kfilemetadata-5.94.0-1  kglobalaccel-5.94.0-1  kguiaddons-5.94.0-1
              ki18n-5.94.0-1  kiconthemes-5.94.0-1  kio-5.94.0-1  kirigami2-5.94.0-1
              kitemviews-5.94.0-1  kjobwidgets-5.94.0-1  knewstuff-5.94.0-2  knotifications-5.94.0-1
              knotifyconfig-5.94.0-1  kpackage-5.94.0-1  kservice-5.94.0-1  ktextwidgets-5.94.0-1
              kwallet-5.94.0-1  kwidgetsaddons-5.94.0-1  kwindowsystem-5.94.0-1  kxmlgui-5.94.0-1
              libaccounts-glib-1.25-7  libaccounts-qt-1.16-3  libdbusmenu-qt5-0.9.3+16.04.20160218-6
              libebur128-1.2.6-1  libimobiledevice-1.3.0-5  libplist-2.2.0-5  libusbmuxd-2.0.2-1
              libvisual-0.4.0-8  libzip-1.8.0-1  media-player-info-24-2  minizip-1:1.2.12-2  mlt-7.6.0-1
              polkit-qt5-0.114.0-1  poppler-qt5-22.05.0-2  purpose-5.94.0-1
              qt5-declarative-5.15.4+kde+r19-1  qt5-graphicaleffects-5.15.4+kde+r0-1
              qt5-location-5.15.4+kde+r2-1  qt5-multimedia-5.15.4+kde+r1-1
              qt5-networkauth-5.15.4+kde+r0-1  qt5-quickcontrols-5.15.4+kde+r0-1
              qt5-quickcontrols2-5.15.4+kde+r4-1  qt5-speech-5.15.4+kde+r1-1
              qt5-wayland-5.15.4+kde+r38-1  qt5-webchannel-5.15.4+kde+r3-1  qt5-webengine-5.15.9-3
              signon-kwallet-extension-22.04.1-1  signon-plugin-oauth2-0.25-1  signon-ui-0.17+20171022-3
              signond-8.61-1  snappy-1.1.9-2  solid-5.94.0-1  sonnet-5.94.0-1  syndication-5.94.0-1
              upower-0.99.18-1  usbmuxd-1.1.1-1  kdenlive-22.04.1-1

Total Removed Size:  486.11 MiB

:: Do you want to remove these packages? [Y/n]
```

What I'm concerned about is that `zoom optionally requires qt5-webengine`, yet `qt5-webengine` appears in the list of packages to be removed. I thought the `-u` option would prevent that. What I want is to remove everything that was installed along with `kdenlive` while keeping anything that is even optionally required by anything else.

How can I do that?

Comment: One great advantage of Archlinux is its documentation : Can't you just read it ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman which says : "To remove a package and its dependencies which are not required by any other installed package: # pacman -Rs package_name!

Comment: I'm well aware of the documentation. Except `sudo pacman -Rs kdenlive` gives me identical output whether I include the `-n` or the `-u` flags or not. Or are you saying that the documentation is so good that if I follow it and run with `-Rs`, `qt5-webengine` won't be removed even though pacman lists it for removal?

Comment: Did you actually install zoom with the webengine option ? Yes ? Then you actually get a problem ! No ? then the webengine package can actually be removed without breaking anything since it is not actually a dependency of anything else. BTW you actually get a (minor) problem somewhere since a dependency cycle was detected.

Comment: `pacman` keeps track only of the installation reason for each package, not which specific package's installation triggered the installation of the dependency. Let's assume package B depends on A, and C optionally depends on A, and B and C are marked as explicitly installed, while A is marked as a dependency. Then if I remove B with `-Rs`, is there a way to not remove A? Or does pacman simply ignore optional dependency relationship? I thought packages counted as orphaned only if they are neither dependencies nor optional dependencies.

Comment: If something is required optionally, it can be removed, it is not preventing the programs from that package to function. Since you effectively backed up the list of packages to be removed by creating this question, just remove them. If you find out you need some of them later, it is easy to install them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to not remove *optional* dependencies I think you'll have to massage the list yourself, remove anything you want to keep.

```
pacman -Rsp kdenlive &| vim -R -
```

then `:%s/\v-\d+(\.\d+)+-\d+$//` to strip the version numbers, delete the entries for packages you want to keep, then build your `pacman -R` from that.

. . . or it might be easier to just reinstall the ones you want, do the `-Rsu` then `pacman --asdeps -S` the ones you want back.